# iTerm2: How to change the color used to highlight search results?

Tags: terminal, iterm

It seems that iTerm2 is hardcoded to highlight search results using a yellow background color. I tried both the latest release and the nightlies but could not find a way to change that color.

Did I miss something? It seems implausible to me, that a terminal emulator with such a degree of customizability would really hardcode a single color while at the same time making virtually everything else user-configurable.

For clarification, here's a screenshot:
[image]
As you can see, I searched the screen contents for the word "stack" and all its occurrences are highlighted in yellow (except for the selected one).

Comment: Don't know exactly what you meant, could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Sure. I've just edited my post.

Answer (score 12):

For iTerm2 Text color changes:

1. From the menus choose Profiles → Open Profiles.
2. Click the Edit Profiles button, then the Colors tabs.

   [image]
3. You can change the colors by clicking on the color wells.

   [image]

You can find iTerm color schemes at [iterm2colorschemes.com](http://iterm2colorschemes.com/).

Comment: That's only for the current match (i.e. as you cycle through all matches). I believe @raimue is correct below in that the yellow color which applies to all matches is not currently configurable.

Comment: None of this works on current iterm. it is currently busted.

Comment: and the color is not yellow. It is light blue.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the yellow color is actually hardcoded in the source code and cannot be configured in the preferences.

Here is the corresponding code snippet where the color is applied:

```
 if (isMatch && !bgselected) {
     aColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1];
 } else ...
```

Source: https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/3a99bb0a0e5924e2d515ec9638a4ffa6731a5682/sources/PTYTextView.m#L6274